# Terraform not reading Symlink file

Tags: terraform

I have a global variables file that i want to use in different subfolders. For that i put it in a folder called shared then i did a symlink in the other subfolders.

```
shared
  .global_variables.tf
s3
  .gloabl_variables -> shared/global_variables.tf
  .main.tf
  .output.tf
  .variables.tf
```

I created the symlink using this command : `ln -s shared/global_variables.tf s3/global_variables.tf`

Now in the S3 folder if i run `terraform init` i'm getting this error :

```
Error: Failed to read file
The file "global_variables.tf" could not be read
```

It seems like terraform is not recognizing the symlink of the file.

How to solve that ?

Thanks

Comment: That symlink looks wrong. Either it should be an absolute path of a relative path. Does the symlink show red when ran with `ls --color`?

Comment: yes its color is red

Comment: ok i solved it. Like you said it was a problem with the path. I have to be in destination folder and then create the symlink using a relative path. thanks

Comment: I've voted to close because it's a typo and not a programming related issue.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I think your response would actually be very helpful as the Answer. I don't see this as a typo issue but rather an understanding of and correct usage of `ls`. Up to you but I would defiantly vote this up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a typo type of issue and unrelated to terraform itself.